# Dropzone.js stop from uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I use http://www.dropzonejs.com/ so that users can drag&drop images in the browser, so that they can then interact with them using JavaScript, so no server-side is involved.

How can I stop Dropzone.js from trying to upload the files?
How can I then access the dragged files via JavaScript (create a new `<img>` tag containing that image)?

Currently I get this error:

[image]

I create the dropzone like this:

```
        <form   action="/file-upload"
                class="dropzone"
                id="my-awesome-dropzone">
        </form>
```

I want the functionality to be the same as their demo on their website, where you can drag images but they are not uploaded.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your Javascript/jQuery part?

Comment: What jQuery part? Dropzone doesn't require any jQuery to work.

Comment: I have the same problem only my error is 419. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @KiraArik Unfortunately I can't remember how I fixed the issue, I think I edited code in the library. Anyway this question is 4 years old and not relevant anymore probably (library has been updated since).

Answer (score 5):

you can set `autoProcessQueue:false`

autoProcessQueue -> When set to false you have to call myDropzone.processQueue() yourself in order to upload the dropped files. See below for more information on handling queues.

and you can navigate to the  tags using jquery

Comment: Tried that, but the error still appears. The script still tries to acces `/file-upload` URL.

Comment: That's all the code, it's posted above. Also tried with some of their options, but with no success.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V3sRj/ Here's a fiddle, but it doesn't seem to work in an iframe (on jsfiddle).

Comment: add this scripy 
`<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", { 
url: "/file/post",
autoProcessQueue:false
});
</script>`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think I will directly edit their Dropzone.js file to remove the AJAX upload part :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and stop the submitting like this:

```
<form action="/file-upload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone"
      onsubmit="return false">
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, as the form is not actually submitted, they use AJAX to send data to server, only take the url from the `action` property.